# Calculate difference between server and user time

Tags: php, javascript, date, time

I'm writing a simple javascript to calculate the time difference between server and user time. But something is going wrong.

If I catch the javascript and php date i have:

```
date("M d Y h:i:s A")
php date : Wed Jun 27 2012 04:10:41 AM  

new Date()
J S date : Wed Jun 27 2012 10:10:40 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

This is correct! I have two different time for local and server time.

Now if I take the seconds time... something goes wrong:

```
(php: date("U"))
sec PHP: 1340784640    

(js new Date().getTime()/1000 )
sec J S: 1340784640
```

I got the same time!

Can you help me to fix it ?

Thanks!

Comment: `date("U")*1000` won't return `1340784640`. `date("U")` already returns in seconds.

Answer (score 4):

`date("U")` and `new Date().getTime()` return the [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_timestamp) which is defined as seconds elapsed since January 1st, 1970 *UTC*. The current locale's timezone is not taken into account.

Use `date('Z')` to get the timezone offset in PHP (in seconds) and [`new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) in JavaScript (in minutes).